# pandas.DataFrame.loc

Tags: pandas

Tenho a seguinte situação:

```
d= {'files': ['f1.txt', 'f2.txt', 'f3.txt'], 'url': ['url1', 'url2', 'url3'], 'nav': [False, True, False]}
df = pd.DataFrame(d)
    files   url    nav
0  f1.txt  url1  False
1  f2.txt  url2   True
2  f3.txt  url3  False
```

Então de posse do DataFrame, posso pesquisar dois campos em determinada condição:

```
df.loc[~df.nav][['files', 'url']]
    files   url
0  f1.txt  url1
2  f3.txt  url3
```

Ou apenas um campo com determinada condição:

```
df.loc[~df.nav]['files']
0    f1.txt
2    f3.txt
```

Aí vem o problema. Quero iterar em um loop for + enumerate

Com apenas 1 campo funciona:

```
for i, file in enumerate(df.loc[~df.nav]['files']):
     print(i, file)

0 f1.txt
1 f3.txt
```

Com 2 campos:

```
for i, file in enumerate(df.loc[~df.nav][['files', 'url']]):
    print(i, file)
0 files
1 url
```

Com 2 campos, desta forma apresenta erro:

```
for i, file in enumerate(df.loc[~df.nav]['files', 'url']):
    print(i, file)
```

Como posso solucionar esta situação?

Comment: "Quero iterar em um loop for + enumerate". Por que não usar o `.iterrows()` para iterar o dataframe? `for index, row in df.loc[~df.nav].iterrows():`, `print(index, row['files'], row['url'])`.

Comment: @AlexCiuffa, tua solução é perfeita para mim. Eu conheci agora esta possibilidade. Muito Obrigado.

Comment: Porque você não coloca esta dica como resposta da pergunta?